# How does USB core decides which HCI driver to use for a USB device driver?

Tags: linux-kernel, driver

I am looking into USB device driver code. looks like all it does is to fill a URB message then calls usb_submit_urb() to pass the message to USB core functions once probe() is called upon matching PCI vendor/product ID.

However I am not able to figure out how USB core relates the device driver to correct HCI driver (xHCI, eHCI etc.)...  what I found is most of HCI drivers register themselves as a platform driver which has a unique name, is that the identifier for usb core to correlate the device driver and host driver?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have usb 3.0 - then kernel uses xhci driver and doesn't need uhci, ohci or ehci drivers. In such configuration you have got only one hci driver and one hci host. Earlier in the USB 2.0 era there were 2 possible configurations:

- ehci with companion controller (ohci or uhci)
- ehci with transaction translator (TT)

In the first situation you need to have both drivers installed - for example ehci and uhci. In the second one only dedicated ehci driver was needed.

So currently when you have only xhci - it registers itself as **the only** usb host driver in linux system. Second thing - it is host driver function to request anything from usb devices - so usb host generates any requests to devices and it is responsible for maintenance of the answers from device. The xhci host driver registers his interrupt and memory area for request maintenance.

I think you need to take a look at this problem from the host (xhci) point of view, not from device point of view, because the host is the master in usb communication and the host initiates any requests. Device is only answering those requests.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. In case I need to write my own HCI, how can I hook it to the device driver? Any specific HCI code inside the linux kernel I can refer to?

Comment: I'm not sure if there is any **direct** connection between HCI and device driver, because I don't remember all the details of the usb sources now.  Maybe urb->hcpriv is used somehow to connect device with HCI? Sorry I have not enough time now for investigating it. I think if you are going to write your own HCI driver you need to only properly register it in usb-core.